# Regex match 3 digits followed by 8 digits or just 8 digits, but do not match 3 digits if it is after decimal

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
'''82290574  BB BBBBB    3.0      195.00       3.75        0.00       0.00       0.00      85.00       113.75      21.61       135.36   220811 11.08.2022       00.000
82290600 BB BBBBB     2.5      375.00       3.13        0.00       0.00       0.00      225.00      153.13      29.09       182.22   220811 11.08.2022       00.000
82290633 BB BBBBB    36.0      270.00      45.00        0.00       0.00       0.00      122.04      192.96      36.66       229.62   220812 12.08.2022       04.110
123 12345678'''
```

I need to change my regex: `\b(?!\.\d{3})(\d{7})(\d)\s*(\d{8})?\b` to match:

`(82290574, 82290600, 82290633, 123 12345678)`

Right now it matches `(82290574, 82290600, 82290633, 12345678)`. The tricky part is that I cannot find a way so that it would not end up in `(82290574, 000 82290600, 000 82290633, 123 12345678)`, like with:

`\b(\d{3})?\s*(\d{7})(\d)\s*(\d{8})?\b`.

I tried looking into negative lookback, but I ended up with `\b(?<![.\d])\d+(?![.\d])(\d{3})?\s*(\d{7})(\d)\s*(\d{8})?\b` which only matches `(123 12345678)`

Answer (score 1):

With your one example, this works:

```py
s = '''82290574  BB BBBBB    3.0      195.00       3.75        0.00       0.00       0.00      85.00       113.75      21.61       135.36   220811 11.08.2022       00.000
82290600 BB BBBBB     2.5      375.00       3.13        0.00       0.00       0.00      225.00      153.13      29.09       182.22   220811 11.08.2022       00.000
82290633 BB BBBBB    36.0      270.00      45.00        0.00       0.00       0.00      122.04      192.96      36.66       229.62   220812 12.08.2022       04.110
123 12345678'''

print(re.findall(r'\b(?:\d{3} )?\d{8}\b', s))
```

```
['82290574', '82290600', '82290633', '123 12345678']
```

It works even without the word breaks in this case.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I should keep the groups, but I a bit modified your answer and this seems to work `\b(?:\d{3} )?(\d{7})(\d)(\d{8})?\b`